# extends ___ = ___ syntax in typescript

Tags: typescript

I recently saw this syntax [here](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/master/modules/store/src/models.ts)

```
export interface ActionReducer<T, V extends Action = Action> {
  (state: T | undefined, action: V): T;
}
```

I am confused about the syntax `<T,V extends Action = Action>`

I could not find documentation for this syntax in typescript . Can anyone point me there . It looks like a new syntax as my build is not able to recognize it and gives me this error :

```
node_modules/@ngrx/store/src/models.d.ts:6:52: ',' expected.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Generic Parameter Defaults

Checked all versions one by one and figured out this is added in version 2.3 
It specifies the default type of `V` . so `V` can be either a class which extends `Action` or if not mentioned will be of type Action.

[Doc](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#generic-parameter-defaults)